# Can bootstrap be used for website plugins without conflicting with site styles and js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Take a website, a CMS, or anything. I want to develop a plugin, or a module basically... but I want to use Bootstrap for the CSS and the javascript components that it offers.

I've heard about namespacing, but does anyone know if this is possible with the JS functionality of bootstrap as well?

There could be a ton of different scenarios at play, so just trying to figure out the best way to handle it.

Comment: *Can bootstrap be used for website...* - Short answer, from my experience: no. There will appear some issues that can be fixed easily I guess. But you can try it on your local machine.

Comment: The upcoming Bootstrap v3.2.0 fixes the `noConflict` feature, and all the events etc. are already namespaces, so yes, the JS will work, modulo the parts that depend on specific CSS class names.

Comment: @cvrebert - By chance do you have a link where I can read about this?

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11966

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if your plugin would be in a separate iframe.

Another wrong way would be to add a class to that plugin outer element and prefix every Bootstrap CSS rule with that class. (I wouldn't do that)

In HTML5 the [style scope attribute](http://www.impressivewebs.com/scoped-styles-html5/) was introduced. This feature would solve your problem but it is not really [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=scope) yet in all major browsers.

You could try [jQuery Scoped CSS Plugin](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin) which should add support for the above HTML5 feature.